# C# ADO NET Насколько легитимно изменять классы, генерируемые на основе имеющихся таблиц?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

Допустим у меня есть несколько связанных таблиц в рамках N-ной ИС, на их основе сгенерированы классы-модели. Я их использую для отображения таблиц и прочего. Так получилось, что мои эти классы иногда носят одинаковую или очень похожую логику. Насколько допустимо лезть руками самому, добавлять какие-то абстракции (отнаследовать сгенерированные классы от какой-то общей сущности, например) и прочее? VS предупреждает, что это не лучшее решение, однако конкретики мало.

Comment: Почитайте про подход EF Code First.

Comment: [Customizing the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#customizing-the-model). Сгенерированный код - это теперь ваш код. Не стесняйтесь менять его.

Comment: если будете менять БД и придется перегенерировать классы заново, то куда денутся ваши правки? Если они в тех де файлах, то не советую из менять. Если вы в своих файлах расширяете классы (наример, если они partial или вы методы расширения дописываете или наследоуетесь) - то ок.